# How can i change the font color for titleForHeaderInSection?

Tags: iphone, fonts, colors

This is what i currently have to display my text, but i can't seem to be able to change the font color of titleForHeaderInSection.

```
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
                                       titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section 
{
    if(section == 0)
        return @"Information";
    if(section == 1)
        return @"Categorize Information";
    return nil;
}
```

How would i be able to change the font color so it could be red for example?

Edit:
I forgot to mention, i'm not using Interface Builder do do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a custom UIView. The best way I have found to do this is in Interface Builder.

### .h

```
@interface MyViewController : UITableViewController {
    IBOutlet UIView *headerView;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIView *headerView;
@end
```

### .m

```
#import “MyViewController.h”
@implementation MyViewController
@synthesize headerView;

#pragma mark Table Stuff
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
                                     viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section 
{
    /* create a UIView here */
    return headerView;
}

#pragma mark Memory Management
- (void)dealloc {
    [headerView release];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

Comment: Please note that the offset of this view is 0, so you might have to use tableview constants to put text at right offsets.

Comment: I'm not using IB, i should of made that clear, sorry i forgot to meantion that.

Comment: If you are not using IB, then you need to programmatically create the view. Other than these 2 options, there is no way to change the color of the header text.

Comment: cheers, i have it sorted now. thank for you help. I accepted your answer.

Answer (score 1):

In the `UITableView` delegate use:

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

to return a custom UIView object, where you can change what you need.  See [link](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UITableViewDelegate).